# Extract elements respectively from text

Tags: regex

I have such a following text:

```
'- `Popen.``terminate`()\n\n  Stop the child. On Posix OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function `TerminateProcess()` is called to stop the child.\n\n\n- `Popen.``kill`()\n\n  Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends SIGKILL to the child. On Windows;...
```

I try to extract a list from the text

```
In [46]: pattern = re.compile(r'-\s(.+)\n\n')
In [49]: matches = pattern.findall(content)
In [50]: matches
Out[50]:
['`Popen.``terminate`()',
 '`Popen.``kill`()',
 '`Popen.``args`',
 '`Popen.``stdin`',
 '`Popen.``stdout`']
```

The result I desire is

```
['Popen.terminate()',
 'Popen.kill()',
 'Popen.args',
 'Popen.stdin',
 'Popen.stdout']
```

I alter the reges with two groups to capture qualifed parts

```
In [55]: pattern2 = re.compile(r'- `(\w+).``(\w+.*)`')
In [64]: matches = pattern2.findall(content)
In [65]: matches
Out[65]:
[('Popen', 'terminate'),
 ('Popen', 'kill'),
 ('Popen', 'args'),
 ('Popen', 'stdin'),
 ('Popen', 'stdout')]
```

It's still not my desired result.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: You missed the argument: `pattern2.findall(content)`

Comment: ```-\s`([^`]*)``([^`]*)`(\(\))?\n\n``` and then concatenate groups 1, 2, 3

Comment: @falsetru my fault.

Comment: so, two groups cannot be concatenated with pure regex @ctwheels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7scaWF/2)

```
-\s`([^`]*)``([^`]*)`((?:\(\))?)\n\n
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/vtA9A9)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"-\s`([^`]*)``([^`]*)`((?:\(\))?)\n\n")

s = ("'- `Popen.``terminate`()\n\n"
    "  Stop the child. On Posix OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function `TerminateProcess()` is called to stop the child.\n\n\n"
    "- `Popen.``kill`()\n\n"
    "  Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends SIGKILL to the child. On Windows;...\n")

for m in re.finditer(r, s):
    print m.group(1) + m.group(2) + m.group(3)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
'- `Popen.``terminate`()\n\n  Stop the child. On Posix OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function `TerminateProcess()` is called to stop the child.\n\n\n- `Popen.``kill`()\n\n  Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends SIGKILL to the child. On Windows;...
```

#### Output

**Note**: The output below doesn't match the OP's expected output because the OP did not post the full string, but only a partial string.

```
Popen.terminate()
Popen.kill()
```

---

### Explanation

- `-` Match the hyphen character `-` literally
- `\s` Match a whitespace character
- `` ` `` Match a grave accent character literally
- `` ([^`]*) `` Capture any number of any characters not present in the set (any character except the grave accent character `` ` ``) into capture group 1
- ``` `` ``` Match two grave accent characters literally
- `` ([^`]*) `` Capture any number of any characters not present in the set (any character except the grave accent character `` ` ``) into capture group 2
- `` ` `` Match a grave accent character literally
- `((?:\(\))?)` Capture the following into capture group 3

  - `(?:\(\))?` Match the following zero or one time

    - `\(\)` Match an opening and closing parenthesis literally `()`
- `\n\n` Match two newline characters